# esbuild throwing `[ERROR] Could not resolve [import statement]` while setting up Ruby on Rails 7/React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

I am trying to set up my first Ruby on Rails 7 with a React app. I installed Ruby on Rails  with the *esbuild* flag:

`rails new project_name -d postgresql -j esbuild`

I [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) added *react*, *react-dom* and *react-router-dom*.

I also created a React './components' folder in my 'app/javascript' folder and I'm importing it into the *application.js* file which is the entry point for the esbuild build script in the *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file.

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import "./controllers";
import "./components";
```

When I execute `bin/dev`, the server spins up properly and I get my project index page. However, esbuild throws the following error.

```
15:05:03 js.1   | started with pid 6552
15:05:03 js.1   | yarn run v1.22.10
15:05:03 js.1   | $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets --watch
15:05:03 js.1   | ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "./components"
15:05:03 js.1   |
15:05:03 js.1   |     app/javascript/application.js:4:7:
15:05:03 js.1   |       4 │ import "./components";
15:05:03 js.1   |         ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
15:05:03 js.1   |
15:05:03 js.1   | 1 error
15:05:03 js.1   | [watch] build finished, watching for changes...
```

I don't understand why this statement can't be resolved when the `import "./controllers";` statement functions just fine. I've looked through the esbuild documentation and searched for other posts here, but I can't seem to find anything that deals with this error.

Hopefully, I'm being dim and there's a simple solution.

My *package.json* file is below as well in case that is useful:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.2.4",
    "esbuild": "^0.16.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
  }
}
```

I have tried changing the name of the components folder and using a different syntax:

```
import 'components';
import '/components';
import "./test";
```

etc... I've read through the esbuild documentation and tried completely building again from scratch and keep getting stuck with the same error.

I'm hoping this is a quick fix and someone less dense than I can help me see the light.

Comment: missing `components/index.js`

Comment: The bounty attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I resolved it(pun intended) by installing turbo-rails

`npm i @hotwired/turbo-rails`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you probably haven't installed some packages that should be inside './components'.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use explicit paths. import "components/Foo" instead of longer paths like import "./app/javascript/components/Foo" are nicer to work with, but the longer pathnames should fix it. With the root of your app as `app/javascript` you may also need to explicitly import index or index.js, unless it gets resolved properly

```
import "./components/index";
```

For the index.js/x entry point of the React app.

Your build command currently looks good

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "esbuild app/javascript/application.js --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=assets"
}
```

You can use alias or shorter pathnames in your esbuild.json config file. Set the components prop to a shortened version like "./app/javascript/components".

```
{
  "alias": {
    "components": "./app/javascript/components",
  },
  "entryPoints": ["app/javascript/application.js"],
  "bundle": true,
  "outdir": "app/assets/builds",
  "publicPath": "assets",
  "sourcemap": true
}
```

If you're going to use Node.js it's a similar config

```
const { build } = require('esbuild');

build({
  entryPoints: ['app/javascript/application.js'],
  bundle: true,
  outdir: 'app/assets/builds',
  publicPath: 'assets',
  sourcemap: true,
  define: {
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
  },
  alias: {
    'components': './app/javascript/components',
  },
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```